# In TypeScript how do I use index type query operator to get only subset of type's properties?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
var o = { x: 5, y: 6, z: 'hi' }
type OnlyNumberProps = keyof typeof o; // 'x' | 'y' | 'z' I want it somehow to be 'x' | 'y'
var p : OnlyNumberProps = 'z' // How to get error here ?
var z : OnlyNumberProps = 'x' // And OK here ?
```

How can I filter the type `OnlyNumberProps` to contain only names of number properties of object `o`?

Comment: if `x` and `z` are both elements of `OnlyNumberProps` why would you expect an error in one case and no error in the other? I dont get what you trying to do

Comment: I want to get type OnlyNumberProps = 'x' | 'y', i.e. to have only those properties from o, which are of type `number`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha possible how? are you basing that on an existing issue?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Nope, my bad. Got mixed with something else.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha ok, so it's just not possible... Added an answer which explains it a bit more.

Comment: Maybe with `type OnlyNumberProps = Pick<o, "x" | "y">`?

Comment: "x" | "y" is explicit definition, the names of my properties might differ form that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible to do.

The closest you can get using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) is this:

```
var o = { x: 5, y: 6, z: 'hi' }
type TypeOfO = typeof o;

type OnlyNumber = {
    [P in keyof TypeOfO]: number;
}
```

But then `OnlyNumber` will be:

```
type OnlyNumbers = { x: number; y: number; z: number; }
```

Which isn't what you're looking for.
There's no way to filter the keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a possible solution:

```
var o = { x: 5, y: 6, z: 'hi' }

type PropertyNames<T> = {
  [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends number ? k : never
} [keyof T]

type Properties<T> = Pick<T, PropertyNames<T>>;

let c1: Properties<typeof o> = {x: 1, y: 3} //ok
let c2: Properties<typeof o> = {x: 1, y: 3, z: "huhu"} //error
let c3: Properties<typeof o> = {} //error
let c4: Properties<typeof o> = {huhu: true} //error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBA9hC8EG8IA8BcECsAaCBPdAbDgF7oDkAFgJZkQC%20AUAwC64AOAphAAphSdhWAORABbDgGcAPABUAfHEQMIEANoBrCFQB2EdR1xQAZhBkBddDI1mIHZMw7aAJhIjaArqIBGHSAH49CHRtDmBfBjo1fUMTcyZWTh4%20AWYqSVkFeG4qAGN1WRxefl9hMXT5OQBuJgAbDmYIHIBGdCKUtOkEjmNoTMQ0CCacfAgAZkiAegmodQY6hpyAJlbkko6pLp6oPoQBobx0UZJ0ACIKd3OTyYnfPjA5%20sbRleLBdc2TbcUEa9uoe-mjQALC92ukPr1vudzuhmGB3BxfmA7kA)

step by step explanation:

1. `typeof o` resolves to `{x: number, y: number, z: string}`
2. A type like

```
 type Foo<T> = {
                 [k in keyof T]:k
               }
```

supplied with the type argument `Foo<typeof o>` resolves to `{x: "x", y: "y", z: "z"}`

3. A type like

```
 type Foo<T> = {
                 [k in keyof T]:T[k]
               }
```

supplied with the type argument `Foo<typeof o>` resolves to `{x: number, y: number, z: string}`

4. We use the conditional type `T[k] extends number ? k : never`. If `T[k]` resolves to a number the conditional type resolves to the key of T as a string literal type otherwise to never.
5. A type like

```
 type Foo<T> = {
                 [k in keyof T]:T[k] extends number ? k : never
               }
```

supplied with the type argument `Foo<typeof o>` resolves to `{x: "x", y: "y", z: never}`

6. In the next step we want to get a union type of the values of the above type. For this we use *indexed access types* [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

```
type PropertyNames<T> = {
  [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends number ? k : never
} [keyof T]
```

supplied with the type argument `PropertyNames<typeof o>` resolves to `"x"|"y"|never`which is the same as `"x"|"y"`

7. In the last step we use the utility type [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to create the desired type

```
Pick<typeof o, "x"|"y">
```

resolves to `{x: number, y: number}`